# Infinite GP in an Infinite AP

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let a, b, c, d,....... be a strictly increasing sequence of positive integers in an arithmetic progression. Prove that there is an infinite subsequence of the given sequence whose terms are in a geometric progression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the arithmetic progression is $\{a,a+m,a+2m,\cdots\}$  then $$\{a, a(1+m),a(1+m)^2,\cdots\}$$ is a subsequence in geometric progression.